# Creating a reusable content part in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following block of HTML to display something, comments for instance:

```
<div class="comment">
...
</div>
```

And this HTML block uses a Comment object to display the data.

I'm using Razor.

How can I create this section so I can re-use it in my other view pages, by simply passing in a comment object.

Is this a partial view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a partial view?

Yes, this looks like a good candidate for a partial view (`~/Views/Shared/_Comment.cshtml`):

```
@model CommentViewModel
<div class="comment">
    ...
</div>
```

and then when you need to use it somewhere:

```
@model SomeViewModel
...
@Html.Partial("_Comment", Model.Comment)
```

Another possibility is to use a display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/CommentViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model CommentViewModel
<div class="comment">
    ...
</div>
```

and then when you need to use it somewhere:

```
@model SomeViewModel
...
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comment) // the Comment property is of type CommentViewModel
```

and yet another possibility is to use the [Html.Action and Html.RenderAction](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) helpers.

So as you can see ASP.NET MVC offers different ways of creating reusable parts.

Comment: vs.net doesn't seem to prefix with an underscore when creating the partial razor page?

Comment: Underscore is a convention for Razor to prevent loading html pages directly. With an underscore it is not reachable anymore directly.